# How Can I run my script after validate,before POST in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to use `WebControls.Validator`(ex. RequiredFieldValidator) for Validation.
But they can submit by button twice and even more.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFld1" runat="server"ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" />

$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    if (waiting) return false;
    waiting = true;
    ShowMyWattingDiv();
)
```

I tried this code, but If InValid I'm waiting too;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.  The key is to use client-side API for ASP.Net validators. Here we are using the property `Page_IsValid` that is available in page whenever you have ASP.Net validators on your page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFld1" runat="server"ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" />

$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    if(!Page_IsValid) {
           return;
    }
    if (waiting) return false;
    waiting = true;
    ShowMyWattingDiv();
)
```

You can also just check if a particular validator is valid using JavaScript like below.

```
var validator = $("#<%=ReqFld1.ClientID%>")[0];
if(validator.isvalid) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Great!

Now I read MSDN document, I see that this property is for "current Validation group".
thank you.

Comment: Yes, this tells whether the page was validated as true or false by ASP.Net validators.

Comment: In  your case, the current validation group is the group for `ReqFld1` which is an empty string.